# image auto saves to device picture album

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a multi platform app - iOS and Android.

One of the features in the app is to capture images. I have a toggle switch in the app settings which allows the user to save the image to the device picture album if the switch is enabled.

This is an issue I can only produce in Android. Even without the toggle switch enabled, the captured photos still save to the device. I have tested this on Android 4.4.2 and 6.0

It does not do this in iOS.

There is nothing in my code to suggest that the photo should still be saved, I have checked it over and over.

Has anyone else come across this? If so what can be done to rectify the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply how FireMonkey captures images on Android. It saves a captured image to a file before handing the pixel data to you. And it does not provide access to the captured image's filename so you can remove the file afterwards.

FireMonkey has an [`IFMXCameraService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXCameraService) interface with a [`TakePhoto()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto) method, which accepts a [`NeedSaveToAlbum`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.TParamsPhotoQuery) option:

[Taking Pictures Using FireMonkey Interfaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces)

However, it is currently broken on Android:

[RSP-13118: [Android] TTakePhotoFromCameraAction saves Image on Disk unexpectedly](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13118)

[RSP-15820: IFMXCameraService TakePhoto , NeedSaveToAlbum False not working](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15820)

Until that is fixed, you could use JNI to access Android's camera APIs directly, then you can do whatever you want with the images.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, much appreciated.